# Django model if constructor called with None then set to chosen value

Tags: python, django

I have:

```
class Scanned(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(timezone.utc), null=False)
```

and in my unit tests I have instantiations of the form:

```
Scanned(time=None)
```

I would like to have that instantiation set the time value to datetime.now(timezone.utc)

I have tried:

```
time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

and

```
time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

I also looked at validators but could not find a way to pass datetime.now() as the value if None.

Comment: Just use `Scanned()`.

Comment: The tests do have instances of Scanned() and these are working nicely with the default I have defined. But there are also instances of Scanned(None) so would like to handle that case.

Comment: well I don't think that's a good idea, since sometimes you want to really use `None`. It is possible, yes, not even that complicated, but probably *not* a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is *not* a good idea to do this, since you might want to set `None` explicitly. If you really want to do this, you can override the constructor and use:

```
from django.models import DEFERRED


class Scanned(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(timezone.utc), null=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(
            *[arg if arg is not None else DEFERRED for arg in args],
            **{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
        )
```

and that's it. What is essentially does is remove the items that are `None`, or put `DEFERRED` in case these are positional parameters. But it is probably *not* a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. I am guessing there is no way to configure DateTimeField to do this? I am also guessing that validators cannot be used to set the value?